# Changing image size using input and buttons

Tags: javascript

I want to change the size of an image with an input and buttons.
I have an input, to which i insert the desired size, an image and 2 buttons.
One for making the image size change according to the input ( for example, if the user typed 300 in the input, the image width and height, will both change to 300px).
And one for making the image size double itself, by clicking the other button.

javascript :

```
var myImg = document.getElementById("myImg")
var input = document.getElementById("insert")

function increaseSize()
{
input.value = myImg.size.width
input.value = myImg.size.height

}

function doubleSize()
{
myImg.style.width * 2
myImg.style.height * 2
}
```

It didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got errors in your code. The first thing I can see is in the increaseSize() function, you are assigning the value to the input, not the image.

`input.value = myImg.size.width`

This line means that you have taken the width of the image and inserted that value into your input, which is the opposite of what you want to do. You want to take the value in your input and inject it into the images `style.width` property. So for starters, change that function (also there is no `.size` property, you wanted `.style`:

```
 // option 1 create within function

 function increaseSize() {

     var myImg = document.getElementById( "myImg" );

     myImg.style.width = input.value;

     myImg.style.height = input.value;

 }

  // option 2 pass as parameters

 var myImg = document.getElementById( "myImg" ); // assign the variables

 var input = document.getElementById( "size" );

 function increaseSize( img, input ) { // create the function

     img.style.width = input.value + 'px'; // assign a unit type to it, as it is a css value

     img.style.height = input.value + 'px';

 }

 increaseSize( myImg ); // run the function, passing in our variables
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `style` to assign width and height using `CSS`, please find below example, where I have used the button to change the size, you can do it with input field as well:

```js
document.getElementById("go").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var img = document.querySelectorAll("#container .image img")[0];
    
    img.style.height = "200px";
    img.style.width = "200px";
});
```

```css
div#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div.image img {
    position:fixed;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button id="go">Increase</button>
<div id="container">
    <div class="image"><img src="http://libcom.org/files/images/library/black-square.jpg"/></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `width` and `height` properties return string with `px` appended to it so remove the `px` part convert it to number and multiply it by 2.

```
var myImg = document.getElementById("myImg")
var input = document.getElementById("insert")

function increaseSize() {
  myImg.style.width = input.value + 'px';
  myImg.style.height = input.value + 'px';
}

function doubleSize() {
  myImg.style.width = Number(myImg.style.width.slice(0,-2)) * 2 + 'px';  
  myImg.style.height = Number(myImg.style.height.slice(0,-2)) * 2 + 'px';  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function changeSize(){
    console.log('Clikced change size!');
    var size=parseInt(document.querySelector('#img_size').value);
    var img=document.querySelector('#img');
    img.width=size;
    img.height=size;
  }

function doubleSize(){
    console.log('Clikced double size!');
    var img=document.querySelector('#img');
    var size=parseInt(img.width)*2;
    img.width=size;
    img.height=size;
  }
```

```html
<img src='http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image1' width='200px'   height="200px" id="img">
<input type="number" id='img_size' >
<button id="change_size" onclick="changeSize()"> Change Size</button>
<button id="double_size" onclick="doubleSize()">Double Size</button>
```